# Changing One Element in 2-Dimensional List Changes all Duplicates of List in List

Tags: python

The purpose of my code is to create a list of lists that contains all combinations of two switches on a binary list.

For example a two switch of `[1,0,0,1,0]` would be `[0,0,0,1,1]`

I have code written that makes the first switch.  I'm trying to write code that takes input of the first switches and makes a second switch.  The order of the input is based on where the first switch was made.  So, the first element-list had it's first switch in its first element, the second element-list had its switch in the second element etc...  I will not switch those elements since it would be undoing the first switch.

Below is what I have.  The `nbrhood` list is the hypothetical list of lists that have already had one switch

```
import itertools

n = 4
nbrhood = [[1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0]]
nbrhood2 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x, (n-1)) for x in nbrhood))
print(nbrhood2)


h = 0
f = 0   
for j in range(0,6):

    f = j//(n-1)

    if n <= h:
        h = 0

    if h != f and h <= n:
        if nbrhood2[j][h] == 1:
            nbrhood2[j][h] = 0
        else:
            nbrhood2[j][h] = 1
        h = h + 1
    elif h == f and h <= n:
        if nbrhood2[j][h+1] == 1:
            nbrhood2[j][h+1] = 0 
        else:
            nbrhood2[j][h+1] = 1  
        h = h + 2
    elif h >= n:
        h = 0

    print(nbrhood2[j])
```

This is the unexpected output:

```
[1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 1]
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
[1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

I don't understand the change I make to one list in `nbrhood2` also applies to the other lists.  Like how the `0` put in the second position in the first list also goes to the second position in the second list.

I've been working on this for hours with no real explanation.  I imagine it has something to do with how Python treats two-dimensional list changes, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists in Python are always by-reference. You're literally repeating the nested values of in `nbrhood` when you do `itertools.repeat(x, (n-1)) for x in nbrhood`.

Simply copy the full list by replacing the first `x` with `x[:]`:

```
itertools.repeat(x[:], (n-1)) for x in nbrhood
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense that it is an issue of nested values.  The specific syntax for itertools.repeat didn't work.  But I did this using numpy `nbrhood2 = np.repeat(nbrhood[:][:],n-1,axis=0)` and it worked.  You found the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple to create a list with all combinations

```
 l  = list(itertools.product([0,1], repeat=4))
[[i] for i in l]
```

Output

```
[[(0, 0, 0, 0)], [(0, 0, 0, 1)], [(0, 0, 1, 0)], [(0, 0, 1, 1)], [(0, 1, 0, 0)], [(0, 1, 0, 1)], [(0, 1, 1, 0)], [(0, 1, 1, 1)], [(1, 0, 0, 0)], [(1, 0, 0, 1)], [(1, 0, 1, 0)], [(1, 0, 1, 1)], [(1, 1, 0, 0)], [(1, 1, 0, 1)], [(1, 1, 1, 0)], [(1, 1, 1, 1)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate across all items for the first switch and in a nested loop iterate across all subsequent items for the second switch. Having the inner loop start at the item after the index of the outer loop ensures that you don't duplicate your coverage.

```
def two_switch(original):
    list_of_2_switches = []
    for i in range(len(original)):
        one_switch = original[:] #copy to retain original
        one_switch[i]=1-one_switch[i]
        for j in range(i+1, range(len(original))):
            second_switch=one_switch[:]
                second_switch[j] = 1-second_switch[j]
            lit_of_2_switches.append(second_switch)
    return list_of_2_switches
```